# android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity did not call through to super.onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Here is my `Android` Media player code. I don't know what I am missing in this code, when I run with breakpoint at line `MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer()` in `Debug` mode. All the files in `zip` folder is played. But when I run the application in normal mode the first file is played and then I get this error:

```
android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.mediaplayer/com.example.mediaplayer.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
```

Code:

```
package com.example.mediaplayer;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {     
    private MediaPlayer mp;    
    private static final String MAIN_TAG ="ERROR";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     try {
    //final String file_loc= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    //Log.i("location",file_loc);
         ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("/storage/emulated/0/AjeshDocument/sample.zip");

         for(int i=1;i<7;i++){

         ZipEntry entry = zip.getEntry("sample/rihanna_"+i+".mp3");                        
         if (entry != null) {
             InputStream in = zip.getInputStream(entry);
             // see Note #3.
             File tempFile = File.createTempFile("_AUDIO_", ".wav");
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
             IOUtils.copy(in, out);

             // do something with tempFile (like play it)
             File f = tempFile;   
             try {
                 if (f.exists())
                 {
                     Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"Audio file found!");
                     MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                     mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
                     mp.prepare();
                     //mp.setLooping(false);
                     mp.start();                         
                     //mp.stop();
                    // mp.release();
                     Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"Pronounciation finished!");
                 }  


               else
                 {
                     Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"File doesn't exist!!");
                 }

             }
             catch (IOException e)
             {
                 Log.i(MAIN_TAG,e.toString());
             }
         }
         else {
             // no such entry in the zip
         }
        } //for end
         mp.release();

     }  
         catch (Exception e) {
         // handle your exception cases...

         Log.i(MAIN_TAG,e.toString());

     }       

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.w("Info", "App Resume");

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.w("Info", "App stopped");

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
     Log.w("Info", "App destoryed");

    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Comment: https://youtu.be/wYlEzYWtesM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't call the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method, i.e the super class' one. Add the call to `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mp;    
    private static final String MAIN_TAG ="ERROR";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // this line is missing

    // your code below ...
```