# Super not called exception in android?

Tags: android

This is my code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
    //Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
}

public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    //Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    //automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    //as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml
    int id=item.getItemId();
    if (id==R.id.action_refresh){
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask=new FetchWeatherTask();
        weatherTask.execute();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

When I execute this I'm getting an " app.SuperNotCalledException" I saw answers for similar questions but I don't get it Pls all helps appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.mediaplayer/com.example.mediaplayer.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851962/android-app-supernotcalledexception-activity-com-example-mediaplayer-com-examp)

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to Arkar Aung

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call [super](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) method from your parent class before overriding it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Hope this will be useful for you.