# Getting an error android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {} did not call through to super.onCreate()

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm making a TV that plays music and youtube videos. I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.newapp, PID: 12965
    android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.newapp/com.example.newapp.YoutubeActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3237)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:81)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1929)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7021)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:486)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:872)
```

This is my code for the youtube activity

```
public class YoutubeActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("youtube", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_main);

        setupVideoPlayer();
    }
```

And this is the code (in another file) that initializes the Activity

```
 private final class ItemViewClickedListener implements OnItemViewClickedListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item,
                                  RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {

            if (item instanceof Radio) {
                Radio radio = (Radio) item;
                Log.d(TAG, "RadioItem: " + item.toString());
                System.out.println(getActivity());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(DetailsActivity.RADIO, radio);

                Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                        getActivity(),
                        ((ImageCardView) itemViewHolder.view).getMainImageView(),
                        DetailsActivity.SHARED_ELEMENT_NAME)
                        .toBundle();
                getActivity().startActivity(intent, bundle);
            } else if (item instanceof Video) {
                Video video = (Video) item;
                Log.e(TAG, "VideoItem: " + item.toString());
                System.out.println(getActivity());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YoutubeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(YoutubeActivity.VIDEO, video);
                Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                        getActivity(),
                        ((ImageCardView) itemViewHolder.view).getMainImageView(),
                        YoutubeActivity.SHARED_ELEMENT_NAME)
                        .toBundle();
                getActivity().startActivity(intent, bundle);
            }
            else if (item instanceof String) {
                if (((String) item).contains(getString(R.string.error_fragment))) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BrowseErrorActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ((String) item), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, if the item clicked is a radio, then it goes to another activity that plays the radio. This works perfectly. But if the item clicked is a video, it goes to the youtube player activity, which gives the exception given in the first code block.
In addition, you can see that I have the super.OnCreate() function, so I am unsure where I'm messing up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Super not called exception in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204066/super-not-called-exception-in-android)

Comment: Unfortunately no, because I have called the super.onCreate() function and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Please show your base activity class also

Comment: I don't have a base activity. For a base activity, do you mean another class that extends my YoutubeBaseActivity? edit: grammar

Comment: Also, YoutubeBaseActivity is part of the Youtube API.

Comment: This is really strange.  Is it possible that you have two classes named `YoutubeActivity` and you're looking at the wrong one? (complete shot-in-the-dark guess)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I only have one class named that. Any other tips I can exercise?

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure `YouTubeBaseActivity` has the super.onCreate() method inside the onCreate event.

Comment: I have the super.onCreate() method in every onCreate event of every class in my app. Any other tips on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work, not by conventional methods though. I just made a new project and copied over the old one to the new. Still not sure what was going wrong but it's working now.